# Algebra steps breakdown

Tags: quadratics

I have been reviewing this question. : [How can I find the points at which two circles intersect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect)

Although during the answering steps I got a little stuck:

From this:

17y2−62y+49=0

To this:

y=(31+82√)17

I am not 100% on the steps taken to achieve this transformation, could someone be so kind as to break down the steps you would follow to solve for y please?

I appreciate the time and help,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the quadratic formula, whenever we have $ay^2+by+c=0,$ then $$y=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}.$$ In particular, here, $a=17,b=-62,c=49.$ Now, $$(-62)^2-4(17)(49)=3844-3332=512=2\cdot256=2\cdot 16^2,$$ so we have $$y=\frac{-(-62)\pm\sqrt{2\cdot 16^2}}{2(17)}=\frac{62\pm16\sqrt2}{34}=\frac{31\pm8\sqrt2}{17}.$$

We can also use a method known as [completing the square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completing_the_square) to get the job done.

Comment: Thank you very much for this Cameron, perfect answer to help me out.