# intersection of 4 circles

Tags: circles, quadratics

Hi I'm doing some programming challenges for fun and I am trying to work out the maths required to solve [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/house-location) problem.  It has been 10 years since I did any maths in anger like this so i'm a bit rusty.  Any help gratefully received.

I have boiled it down to the following
given points p0, p1, p2, p3 and factors a and b, find pS subject to the following conditions.

pS is r0 from p0

pS is a * r0 from p1

pS is r1 from p2

pS is b * r1 from p3

i've tried a number of ways of doing this but I think the most promising is by creating 4 equations:

$$(x_S - x_0)^2 + (y_S - y_0)^2 = r_0^2 \tag 1$$
$$(x_S - x_1)^2 + (y_S - y_1)^2 = a^2r_0^2 \tag 2 $$
$$(x_S - x_2)^2 + (y_S - y_2)^2 = r_1^2 \tag 3 $$
$$(x_S - x_3)^2 + (y_S - y_3)^2 = a^2r_1^2 \tag 4 $$

this gives me 4 unknowns, xS, yS, r1 and r0

so I am trying to work through the maths to simplify an equation down so that I can solve it programatically.

I can eliminate r0 and r1 quite easily but eliminating xS or yS is where I am struggling

using equations 1 and 2 I've got to the below which is where I have got stuck.

xS^2(1 - a^2) - 2xS(x1 - a^2 * x0) + yS^2(1 - a^2) - 2yS(y1 - a^2 * y0) + a^2(x0^2 + y0^2) + x1^2 + y1^2 = 0

How can I rearrange this for yS? so that I can use it to solve equations 3 and 4?

xS^2(1 - b^2) - 2xS(x3 - b^2 * x2) + yS^2(1 - b^2) - 2yS(y3 - b^2 * y2) + b^2(x2^2 + y2^2) + x3^2 + y3^2 = 0

or am I going about this completely the wrong way?

thanks Shep

---

### Further Progress

Thanks to Yves for the guidance on removing the square terms but I am now stuck again as I don't seem to have enough equations to eliminate all of the variables.

$$2x_S(x_0 - x_1) + 2y_S(y_0-y_1) + x_1^2 - x_0^2 + y_1^2 - y_0^2 = r_0^2(a^2-1)\tag5$$
$$2x_S(x_0 - x_2) + 2y_S(y_0-y_2) + x_2^2 - x_0^2 + y_2^2 - y_0^2 = r_1^2 - r_0^2\tag6$$
$$2x_S(x_0 - x_3) + 2y_S(y_0-y_3) + x_3^2 - x_0^2 + y_3^2 - y_0^2 = b^2r_1^2 - r_0^2\tag7$$

my next step would be to rearrange 5 for r0^2 and substitute into 6 and 7 which I've done and then to rearrange for r1^2 and substitute again however this still leaves me with only 1 equation containing x and y.

Comment: Subtracting the first equation from the other three gives you three linear equations, much easier to handle.

Comment: thank you! that's something to get me started! I'm just working this through now!

Comment: So i've worked this through and hit a problem.  While subtracting equation 1 from 2, 3 and 4 eliminates the square terms it doesn't eliminate a variable which means I'm one equation short to solve for 4 variables.

Comment: Your equations are wrong. [This](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm) might help set them up correctly.

Comment: @dshin which ones?  the first 4 or my new ones?  the first 4 I got from http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/circle-equations.html

Comment: The link's formulas are correct but you did not copy them correctly. Your first 4.

Comment: @dshin  Ah I see that's a typo in my question.  The follow through workings are based off my notes which are correct.  Will correct my question.

Answer (score 0):

Equations 1 and 2 imply that the point lies on a circle. You can find the equation of that circle by eliminating r0.

Similarly find the equation of the circle implied by equations 3 and 4.

Then your problem boils down to finding the intersection of two circles. This can be easily solved, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect).

Be careful about edge cases.