# calculate points coordinates on plane from their distances matrix

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given a list of `points` on a plane is simple to generate a `distances` list between each pair of points.

Pseudo  Code:

```
distances = []
for each point_a in points at index_a
  for each point_b in points at index_b having index_b > index_a
    dist = sqrt(abs(point_a.x-point_b.x)^2 + abs(point_a.y-point_b.y)^2)
    push [index_a, index_b, dist] in distances
```

Now, having `distances` is it possible to calculate back the coordinates of `points`?
Obviously *relative* coordinates, with any translation/rotation/symmetry.
With an approximation too, if it could simplify computation.
It would be even ok if the generated `points` wouldn't represent the originals points, the important thing is that the `distances` list fits them.
....
*edit*: Pseudo Code appreciated !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, generally speaking you can do this, up to rigid motions and reflections. Take $n+1$ points (assuming your space is $\mathbb{R}^n$) and assemble a simplex (triangle, tetrahedron, etc) from them. The simplex is unique up to isometry: you can see this by comparing the number of degrees of freedom $(n+1)n$ to the number of length constraints, and the dimension of the orthogonal group $O(n)$ and translation group.

Now that you have your simplex, add all of the other points: each point's position is overdetermined given the positions of the points in the simplex.

---

If you are on the plane, the points are $p_i$ and the distance between points $i$ and $j$ is $d_{ij}$:

1. Put the point $p_1$ anywhere you like.
2. Draw the circle of radius $d_{12}$ centered at $p_1$.
3. Put the point $p_2$ anywhere on that circle.
4. Draw the circle of radius $d_{13}$ centered at $p_1$, and the circle of radius $d_{23}$ centered at $p_2$. If your distances came from some (unknown) layout of the points in the plane, these two circle must intersect in at least one point. Pick one point of intersection and put $p_3$ there.

You now have your simplex. Follow the next step for every remaining point $p_i$:

5. Draw the circle of radius $d_{1i}$ centered at $p_1$ and $d_{2i}$ centered at $p_2$. These two circles will intersect in at least one point (typically two). To decide which to pick for $p_i$, draw the circle of radius $d_{3i}$ centered at $p_3$; it will pass through one of the intersection points. Pick that one.

Comment: @Fundamental wrote the algorithm out step by step

Comment: @user7530 That looks ok, however I would really appreciate a Pseudo Code for it! (i was implicitly asking for it when i showed mine)

Comment: @aleclofabbro Full code might be more suited for Stackoverflow, but to get started take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect