# Calculate the intersection of a line segment on the radius of a circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Given the length and one endpoint of the line segment, how can we find the other endpoint so that it is on the radius of a circle (known coordinates and radius)?

Assume that there is at least one solution.

All variables on the diagram are known except x and y.

[image]

Comment: will you please make your question a bit more clear by giving a related figure or graph that  you want the answer be like?

Comment: @RakibulIslamPrince edited

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I find the points at which two circles intersect?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $d$ is suitable (you said assume there's a solution), the solutions will come from finding the intersection of the two circles
$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2 \qquad\text{and}\qquad (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=d^2.$$
This turns into solving one quadratic and one linear equation. You'll have a unique solution when $d=\sqrt{(h-a)^2+(k-b)^2}\pm r$, two solutions if $d$ is between those numbers, and no solutions otherwise.