# Trigonometry - drawing algorithm

Tags: trigonometry

I am NOT a mathematician! 
I have what should be a relatively simple trig problem that I am looking for a general algorithm to put in some code. I have 3 lines of fixed length. The origin (C) of one of the lines can rotate around a circle, I am looking to be able to calculate point B for any position of (C) on the circle - the position of C is altered by rotating DC.
I would then hope to be able to use any values AD, AB, BC, CD, AE and DE to calculate point B. DE will always be horizontal and AE always vertical.

Hope this makes sense!

[Trig Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L3PN.png)

Comment: I see this as a problem where you have to find the intersection of two circles: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/256100/how-can-i-find-the-points-at-which-two-circles-intersect. The first circle is centred at $A$, and the other circle is centred at $C$. (It, also, is rotating about a point, but let's assume that we know the coordinates of the point $C$)

Comment: Calculate the distance from A to C and the result is a SSS triangle because A to B is 500 while C to B is 320.